# Connecting 30 Water Heater with 15 Gallon Under the Counter

Tags: plumbing, water, heater

Could someone point me in the right direction how to install a 30 gal water heater with an existing 15 gallon under the counter water heater? It would be installed in the carport storage room beside 200 amp electrical panel. It would be about 40-50 ft away from under the counter heater. Would I tie into the existing heater somehow?

Comment: Are you wanting to plumb these heaters in series or in parallel?

Comment: I would prefer parallel

Comment: This just doesn't make a whole lot of sense without more info.  Which outlets are being served by the heater(s)? What's the motivating factor for more water heaters?

Comment: I would connect them in series especially if it is more hot water you need than either will supply on it's own.